# ShieldUI Grid Edit and Delete Buttons disappear after Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, shieldui

I am trying to use a ShieldUI Data Grid with filtering and editing together. I am using in an ASP.Net core application. 
The funny thing is - I added the Edit and Delete Button to the rows and it initially seems to work. But when I am trying to change the filter value via javascript function, the correct filtered values are appearing in the rows, but the Edit and Delete Buttons are disappeared and no longer available. I can still use the Insert Button on the Top, but even there I cannot save new values as the Edit/Update Button is no longer visible. 
Does anyone else having this problem and probably knows a way around this?

This is the gridview-code:

```
@(Html.ShieldGrid()
    .Name("actionsGrid")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Events(eb => eb
            .Error(@<text>
                function (event) {
                    if (event.errorType == "transport") {
                    // transport error is an ajax error; event holds the xhr object
                    alert("transport error: " + event.error.statusText);

                    // reload the data source if the operation that failed was save
                    if (event.operation == "save") {
                    this.read();
                    }
                    }
                    else {
                    // other data source error - validation, etc
                    alert(event.errorType + " error: " + event.error);
                    }
                }
                </text>))
        .Remote(rb => rb
            .ReadConfiguration(r => r
                .Add("type", "GET")
                .Add("url", "/api/admin/tree/params")
                .Add("dataType", "json"))
            .ModifyObject(m => m
                .Modify(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.ModifyOptions.Create, @<text>
                    function (items, success, error) {
                        var newItem = items[0];
                        newItem.data.actionid = $("#actionReference").html();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/api/admin/tree/params",
                                dataType: "json",
                                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: JSON.stringify(newItem.data),
                            complete: function (xhr) {
                            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            if (xhr.status == 201) {
                            var location = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
                            success();
                            return;
                        }
                        }

                    error(xhr);
                    }
                    });
                    }
                </text>)
                .Modify(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.ModifyOptions.Update, @<text>
                    function (items, success, error) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "/api/admin/BaseScenarioApi/tree/@Model.ScenarioId/params",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(items[0].data)
                    }).then(success, error);
                    }
                    </text>)
                .Modify(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.ModifyOptions.Remove, @<text>
                function (items, success, error) {
                var actionid = items[0].data.actionId;
                var paramname = items[0].data.paramName;
                $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/api/admin/BaseScenarioApi/tree"?paramName=" + paramname
                }).then(success, error);
                }
                    </text>                                                                                                                                                            )))
        .FilterGroup(
            ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FilterCondition.Or,
            new object[]{
                new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                    {"path", "actionId"},
                    {"filter", "eq"},
                    {"value", "dummy"}
                },
                new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                    {"path", "actionId"},
                    {"filter", "isnull"}
                },
            })
        .Schema(sb => sb
            .Fields("actionId", fb => fb.Path("actionId").Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FieldType.String))
            .Fields("orderNumber", fb => fb.Path("orderNumber").Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FieldType.Number))
            .Fields("isActive", fb => fb.Path("isActive").Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FieldType.Boolean))
            .Fields("paramType", fb => fb.Path("paramType").Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FieldType.String))
            .Fields("paramName", fb => fb.Path("paramName").Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FieldType.String))))
    .Sorting(true)
    .RowHover(false)
    .Columns(cb => cb.Field("orderNumber").Title(Html.DisplayNameFor(t => _actionParView.OrderNumber)).Width(120))
    .Columns(cb => cb.Field("isActive").Title(Html.DisplayNameFor(t => _actionParView.isActive)).Width(120))
    .Columns(cb => cb.Field("paramType").Title(Html.DisplayNameFor(t => _actionParView.ParamType)).Editor(@<text>ParamTypeSelection</text>).Width(120))
    .Columns(cb => cb.Width(140).Title(" ")
        .Buttons(b => b.CommandName("edit").Caption("Edit"))
        .Buttons(b => b.CommandName("delete").Caption("Delete")))
    .Events(ev => ev
        .GetCustomEditorValue(@<text>CustomEditorValue</text>            )
        )
    .ToolBar(tb => tb.Buttons(b => b.CommandName("insert").Caption("Add Parameter"))
        .Position(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.Grid.PositionOptions.Top)
        .Buttons(b => b.CommandName("edit").Caption("Edit"))
        .Position(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.Grid.PositionOptions.Top))
    .PagingConfiguration(pb => pb.PageSize(5))
    .Editing(eb => eb.Enabled(true)
        .Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.Grid.EditingTypeOptions.Row)))
```

I added a function, which should update my GridView Filter after I selected a different option in a Treeview (also ShieldUI..).

```
 function selectTree(e) {
       var actionsGrid = $("#actionsGrid").swidget();
       actionsGrid.dataSource.filter.or[0].value = e.item.actionId; 
       actionsGrid.refresh();
    }
```

As said previously, the function is working and is filtering the correct values which are also shown in the Grid - but the "Edit" and "Delete" - Buttons have disappeared.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is weird... Could you provide a JSBin example for the complete setup that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?